# How to prevent back button to go default auth home page in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

After successful login, If click on the browser's back button then It goes to this URL  "http://127.0.0.1:8000/home". In my project, there is no such URL. I'm using laravel UI 3 package for authentication. I don't want to go to that home page. I deleted this route

```
 Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])
```

I made my custom home page where the user is redirected after successful login & It's worked perfectly. But the problem is after login, if I click the browser's back button then It's going to the default home page which is not good.

How to solve that problem?

Comment: change the `RouteServiceProvider::HOME` constant

Comment: As @IGP mentioned, you can change it from `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` :
`public const HOME = '/home';` to, `php
public const HOME = '/dashboard';` Then it will throw you to the `/dashboard`

Comment: Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RedirectIfAuthenticated` (`app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php`) does the redirect.

```php
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  ...$guards
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

It uses the `RouteServiceProvider::HOME` constant to know where it should redirect. You could change that constant in the `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` file.

```php
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * This is used by Laravel authentication to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = '/home';
```